# Not opening word document

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to open a word document from Excel using VBA. Here is the code:

```
Sub Openuserguiddoc()
   'Open an existing Word Document from Excel
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("User Guide to VR Referrals.docx")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Documents.Open "N:\MHBS\Education and Employment\VR Reports\VRU REFERALS\Past Years Referrals\User Guide to VR Referrals.docx"
End Sub
```

It hangs up on `Set objWord = CreateObject("User Guide to VR Referrals.docx")`.
 But for the life of me, I can't figure out what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you need to provide the full path?

Comment: No, he should supply "Word.Application" as argument to CreateObject

Comment: @z32a7ul nope, this method also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you can also try it without late-binding, as we seem to be having trouble here.

In the VBA Editor, goto Tools then References:

[image: Ref]

Then tick Microsoft Word in the list (your version number may be different)

[image]

Then use this code:

```
Sub Openuserguiddoc()
   'Open an existing Word Document from Excel
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Set objWord = New Word.Application
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Documents.Open "N:\MHBS\Education and Employment\VR Reports\VRU REFERALS\Past Years Referrals\User Guide to VR Referrals.docx"
End Sub
```

Let us know how you get on!

Comment: That works exactly as planned. Thanks everybody for your help. Andrew, your guide for non late binding was very concise, and easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

`CreateObject("")` is used for creating a named object, such as Word.Application, not for opening files. Try `CreateObject("Word.Application")`

You may also want to change `Documents.Open` to `objWord.Documents.Open`, because if you are creating an object with create object, its usually because you havent made a reference to it, so Excel doesnt know what the `Document` object is or does, but `objWord` does.

Additionally, when you have this document open, if you want to do something with it using VBA, you will need to `set` another object to link to it, and you do this by putting a `set` statement infront of the Documents.Open statement, in much the same way as you did with `CreateObject`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject(“Word.Application”)
Set obj­Doc = objWord.Documents.Open "N:\MHBS\Education and Employment\VR Reports\VRU REFERALS\Past Years Referrals\User Guide to VR Referrals.docx"
```

Comment: I have tried the suggestions posted, and they have hung up at various locations. The entire path is `N:\MHBS\Education and Employment\VR Reports\VRU REFERALS\Past Years Referrals\User Guide to VR Referrals.docx"`.  I failed to mention the error the code **Run time error 429. Active X component can't create object.** The user is no making any changes to the document, just reading.

Comment: I made the changes that ASH suggested & nothing happens. It is possible that I missed something. Here is the code as it is written now: `Sub Openuserguiddoc()
'Open an existing Word Document from Excel
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("N:\MHBS\Education and Employment\VR Reports\VRU REFERALS\Past Years Referrals\User Guide to VR Referrals.docx")
objWord.Application.Visible = True
End Sub`.

Answer (score 1):

These few modifications shall fix it:

1- Provide the full path of the file, such as:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("N:\MHBS\Education and Employment\VR Reports\VRU REFERALS\Past Years Referrals\User Guide to VR Referrals.docx")
```

But then your object is of the type `Word.Document`, not Word.Application.

2- To make it visible, you need:

```
objWord.Application.Visible = True
```

3- later you open another document in Word, so use the word Apllication object

```
Set newDoc = objWord.Aplication.Documents.Open("N:\MHBS\Education and Employment\VR Reports\VRU REFERALS\Past Years Referrals\User Guide to VR Referrals.docx")
```

Comment: The fact that this works makes me dissapointed in Microsoft. How does this enforce logical object creation? Anyone looking at the code won't know nessecarily what the object will be set to, and this is just bad coding practice

Comment: @AndrewWynn I am not a MS employee so I am not into a war to defend their choices. But they made this for convenience, just like when you click on a named document in the explorer you dont need to specify the application, because the information is available in the registry. Also remember that the OP chose `late-binding` as well, so it is their choice to "guess" what the resulting object does...

Comment: I'm not irritated with you, and I'm sorry if it came across like that, but VBA is an entry level language, so adding in this sort of capability for convenience is great for the user, but terrible if they ever go on to code something that other people have to debug.

Comment: @AndrewWynn No problem for the discussion :). FWIW, I also have the same critics, but people have different preferences. In my answers I generally try to be as close as possible to the style I see in the question. Cheers.

Comment: @FrankM I saw your comment above, but what do you mean by *nothing happens*? I have some doubts, could you try to reboot the system and then try the macro before opening Word? Also, it seems that you have a mapped network drive, did you make sure that it is accessible? What happens if you test the macro with a local file?